# Inserting a timestamp(0) column on Teradata using Preparedstatement on Java

Tags: java, timestamp, prepared-statement, teradata

Lets supose the folowing table:

```
CREATE MULTISET TABLE DATABASE.TABLE ,NO FALLBACK ,
   NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
   NO AFTER JOURNAL,
   CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
   DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
   (
     START_DATE TIMESTAMP(0) FORMAT 'DD-MMM-YYYYBHH:MI:SS',
     STATUS DECIMAL(5,0) ,
     PROCESS VARCHAR(100) CHARACTER SET LATIN CASESPECIFIC NOT NULL
   )
PRIMARY INDEX ( PROCESS)
UNIQUE INDEX ( PROCESS, START_DATE );
```

What I would like to do is insert into that table using PreparedStatement on Java, but it is not working.. =/

that is what I am doing on Java:

```
setConnection(); //IT IS OK, SO DONT WORRY!! =)

String insert = "insert into DATABASE.TABLE (START_DATE , STATUS, PROCESS)";

PreparedStatement  pstm = getConnection().prepareStatement(insert);

ArrayList<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();
values.add(0, new java.sql.Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime()));
values.add(1, new Integer(0));
values.add(2, "TEST_PROCESS");

for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
{
    if (values.get(i).getClass().equals(Integer.class))
        pstm.setInt(i+1, (Integer) values.get(i));

    if (values.get(i).getClass().equals(String.class))
        pstm.setString(i+1, (String) values.get(i));

    if (values.get(i).getClass().equals(Timestamp.class))
        pstm.setTimestamp(i+1, (Timestamp) values.get(i));

    if (values.get(i).getClass().equals(Date.class))
        pstm.setDate(i+1, (Date) values.get(i));

    if (values.get(i).getClass().equals(Double.class))
        pstm.setDouble(i+1, (Double) values.get(i));

    if (values.get(i).getClass().equals(Float.class))
        pstm.setFloat(i+1, (Float) values.get(i));
}

pstm.execute();
```

And that is the error I am getting:

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 15.10.00.05] [Error 5404] [SQLState HY000] Datetime field overflow.
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.util.ErrorFactory.makeDatabaseSQLException(ErrorFactory.java:308)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.ReceiveInitSubState.action(ReceiveInitSubState.java:109)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.subStateMachine(StatementReceiveState.java:307)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementReceiveState.action(StatementReceiveState.java:196)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.StatementController.runBody(StatementController.java:123)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.statemachine.PreparedStatementController.run(PreparedStatementController.java:46)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:386)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDStatement.executeStatement(TDStatement.java:328)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDPreparedStatement.doPrepExecute(TDPreparedStatement.java:165)
at com.teradata.jdbc.jdbc_4.TDPreparedStatement.execute(TDPreparedStatement.java:2598)
at ProcessStatus.set(ProcessStatus.java:71)
at CMain.main(CMain.java:42)
```

I know I could change the **START_DATE** data type to TIMESTAMP(3) for example, but it doesnt seems the tight thing to do, so thats why I am asking for your help.

Anyway, I appreciate your time and help. Thank you everybody!!!

Comment: Where are the question marks in your SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found a way to do that.

basicaly I have used a SimpleDateFormat and add the Timestamp as an String and not as an Timestamp object.

something like that:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Timestamp ts =  new java.sql.Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());
String mydate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(ts);
ArrayList<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();

values.add(0, mydate);
```

here is how it looks like in the final code::

```
setConnection(); //IT IS OK, SO DONT WORRY!! =)

String insert = "insert into DATABASE.TABLE (START_DATE , STATUS, PROCESS)";

PreparedStatement  pstm = getConnection().prepareStatement(insert);

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
Timestamp ts =  new java.sql.Timestamp(calendar.getTime().getTime());
String mydate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss").format(ts);

ArrayList<Object> values = new ArrayList<Object>();

values.add(0, mydate);

values.add(1, new Integer(0));
values.add(2, "TEST_PROCESS");

for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
{
    if (values.get(i).getClass().equals(Integer.class))
        pstm.setInt(i+1, (Integer) values.get(i));

    if (values.get(i).getClass().equals(String.class))
        pstm.setString(i+1, (String) values.get(i));

    if (values.get(i).getClass().equals(Timestamp.class))
        pstm.setTimestamp(i+1, (Timestamp) values.get(i));

    if (values.get(i).getClass().equals(Date.class))
        pstm.setDate(i+1, (Date) values.get(i));

    if (values.get(i).getClass().equals(Double.class))
        pstm.setDouble(i+1, (Double) values.get(i));

    if (values.get(i).getClass().equals(Float.class))
        pstm.setFloat(i+1, (Float) values.get(i));
}

pstm.execute();
```

Thanks, and I hope it helps someone!!